# How to bypass React's error handling of colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Trying to figure out if there is away of bypassing React's error handling for colors.

The first inner DIV serves as a default with an empty background if a user inputs a color that is incorrect, whether a Hex color or a string.
The second inner DIV sits on top of the first, and is meant to display the color of this.props.value.
This works fine to show my `emptyBackground` value in the first div, and when a correct color is inputed by the user, say orange, the second div will display a background color of orange, overlapping the first.

Now if I were to change `orange` to `orangered`, this div will change to `orangered`.

The part I am trying to get around is when I type orangere, it will still show the original orange color instead of the default background of the second div. It seems that react will not prompt a re-render when an improper color has been entered. Any way to get around this?

```
export default class ColorRender extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange(e) {
  this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
}

render() {
   const disabled = this.props.disabled || this.props.readonly;

return (
  <div
    style={{ position: 'relative' }}
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      value={this.props.value}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      style={{
        marginBottom: 20,
        width: `calc(100% - ${COLOR_BOX_WIDTH}px - ${COLOR_BOX_MARGIN_RIGHT}px - ${COLOR_BOX_MARGIN_LEFT}px)`,
      }}
      disabled={disabled}
    />

    <div
      style={{
        ...contentStyle,
        backgroundImage: `url(${emptyBackground})`,
      }}
    />

    <div
      className="color-display"
      style={{
        ...contentStyle,
        backgroundColor: this.props.value,
        zIndex: 1000,
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, this is a standard DOM element behavior (as [noted by @jered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014267/5157454)), you can override it with react.

Wrap the `.color-display` div with another div (the `.color-display-wrapper`), and set the default color on it. Update the `.color-display` background via a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). If the value in the variable is invalid, the background color would be transparent, and the wrapper's background would be displayed.

```js
class ColorRender extends React.Component {
  state = { color: 'orange' };
  
  onChange = (e) => this.setState({ color: e.target.value });

  render() {
    const {color} = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
        
        <div className="color-display-wrapper">
          <div 
            className="color-display"
            style={{ '--color': color }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ColorRender />,
  demo
);
```

```css
:root {
  --color: transparent;
}

.color-display-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/200);
}

.color-display {
  position: relative;
  background: var(--color);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: originally, instead of using a default color, i had a div with a default background image, would that cause any issues?

Comment: Not if you'll move the default image to the wrapper.

Comment: @FerdinandIsmael - updated to a default image as background.

Comment: thanks it did work, the --color, may i know what that is essentially doing or what it is specifically you are invoking? it looks like it connects to the css styling but not like normal css would. Just want to better understand whats going on
edit: im assuming its this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: I forgot to add the [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) link. The idea is simple, instead of setting the background color directly, you set a variable that does that. If the value is incorrect, the background is resetted back to the default (transparent), instead of using the previous working color.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has nothing to do with React. Modern browsers will simply ignore attempts to set color properties to an unsupported value. You can easily try this yourself by opening up the dev console, selecting a DOM element somehow, and setting its color to orange with something like `myElement.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'`. Then try setting it to an invalid value like 'orangere'. The element will remain orange instead of reverting to an default or inherited value.

Probably the best way to address this would be to manually check that the user input is a valid color. Something like the [is-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-color) package will check not only if it's a [valid color name](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp), but HEX and RGB values as well. If the user input is valid, have React render it as usual. But if it's invalid, you can catch that and use a default or inherited value instead.